# Get my public IP from ifconfig.co using netcat

Tags: ip, netcat

From my Android TV box, I would like to get my public IP and other related info from ifconfig.co, but it does not seem to work. If I try this code, it works fine:

```
adb  -s 192.168.1.125:5555 shell netcat icanhazip.com 80 <<< $'GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: icanhazip.com\n\n'
```

... while this one returns an empty string:

```
adb  -s 192.168.1.125:5555 shell netcat ifconfig.co 80 <<< $'GET / HTTP/1.1\nHost: ifconfig.co\n\n'
```

On the other hand, both sites work fine with curl (from another machine).

My objective is to **retrieve the page ifconfig.co/json using netcat** (the only available tool on the TV box) directly from shell (using a single line command). Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the site `ifconfig.co` with `ipinfo.io`

Comment: yes, it worked! Thank you very much.

Comment: @user1202609: you have designated this as the "accepted" answer, which is a good thing. you should consider ***upvoting*** this answer. i.e. it is a "useful" answer, and it is also the "selected" answer.